# How to add class to the clicked button and remove a class to the previously clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How will I add a class to the clicked button and remove a class to the previously clicked button. I want to have a single active button only per click

My html looks like this

```
<div class="nav-button">
   <button id="btn-all">All</button>
   <button id="btn-chicken">Chicken</button>
   <button id="btn-pizza">Pizza</button>
   <button id="btn-pasta">Pasta</button>
   <button id="btn-drinks">Drinks</button>
</div>
```

And my jquery looks like this

```
$('.nav-button button').on('click', function(){
     $(this).addClass("active")
})
```

**I dont want to select the buttons one by one because this group of button is dynamic. I just only use the html example above to show my buttons in html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply first remove the class from *all* buttons:

```
 $("div.nav-button button").removeClass('active');
```

So you can do:

```js
$('.nav-button button').on('click', function(){
     $("div.nav-button button").removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-button">
   <button id="btn-all">All</button>
   <button id="btn-chicken">Chicken</button>
   <button id="btn-pizza">Pizza</button>
   <button id="btn-pasta">Pasta</button>
   <button id="btn-drinks">Drinks</button>
</div>
```